# These two Objective-C functions crash with no message

Tags: objective-c, function

I'm building a header with a bunch of functions to do some astronomy math and so far so good, except these two functions crash the debugger with a `Debugging terminated.` message and nothing else.  The `NSLog` statements print to the console just fine with the correct answers, but they crash.  Any ideas?

```
float calcTimeJulianCent(float julianDate) {
 NSLog(@" -calcTimeJulianCent");
 float tCentury = (julianDate - 2451545.0) / 36525.0;
 NSLog(@"  -calculation complete, tCentury = %1.4f", tCentury);
 return tCentury;
}

float calcJDFromJulianCent(float tCentury) {
 NSLog(@" -calcJDFromJulianCent");
 float julianDate = tCentury * 36525.0 + 2451545.0;
 NSLog(@"  -calculation complete, tCentury = %1.4f", julianDate);
 return julianDate;
}
```

And here's the method that calls the functions:

```
- (IBAction)doMath {
 NSLog(@"-%@:%s called", [self class], _cmd);

    // other calls that work

 float julianCentury = calcTimeJulianCent(julianDay);
 NSLog(@"  -calcTimeJulianCent called: %@", julianCentury);

 float backToJulianDate = calcJDFromJulianCent(0.1092);
 NSLog(@"  -calcJDFromJulianCent called: %@", backToJulianDate);

    // more calls that work
}
```

EDIT: Answer - silly mistake.  The functions return `floats` and I used `%@` in the NSLog which is for strings.  You'd think Xcode could do more than just crash over that.

Comment: If you step through it with the debugger, what line does the crash happen on?

Comment: What platform are you on? Using GDB? Does it say "Debugging terminated" or "Debugger stopped"? Is there a return status printed? Could it be that the error is in some code outside of these functions? Do your functions return at all?

Comment: That's interesting - I put a breakpoint in the method that calls these functions, and then stepped through.  I wasn't getting all the debug info until I did that.  Now I can see that it crashes after the function returns.  Updating the question to show what the call looks like...

Comment: I'm using Xcode.  It says `terminated`, not `stopped`.  And now that I step through, it gets a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious but those function names are different. Is that right? The SO equivalent of asking if it's plugged in and switched on :) Edit: you've fixed it now.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed.  The `NSLog` that prints the results had a `%@` for those arguments because I copied it from the previous function call that returned a string.  Changing to `%1.4f` fixed it.  Man I wish Xcode was better at finding silly typo stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your edit. The reason is crashes is because `NSLog` expects to find a pointer to an *object* -- that is, a memory location -- when it finds the `%@` format specifier. Obviously a floating-point number cannot be a valid memory address, so the program crashes. Xcode doesn't  fix it because `NSLog` takes a string and a variable list of arguments. However, in C, you cannot specify types for varargs, so there's no way to tell what type of arguments `NSLog` *should* take, in the general case.

(gcc does provide some format-specifier checking when you call `printf`, but the same doesn't happen with `NSLog`.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  It's nice to solve a problem, but even better to know `why` it got solved!